# Rails: link_to a specific users show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a link that takes you to a specific users page in my rails app. The link currently looks like this:

```
<%= link_to track.user.username, user_path(@user) %>
```

However, I get this error when I try to refresh:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]
```

Can somebody suggest what I could be missing? I'm not sure how to specifically reference the users id in the code.

Thanks,

Ant

Comment: looks like `@user` isnt defined in that code.

Comment: Can you check the value of @user isn't nil?

Comment: can you upload routes.rb and user controller to this post

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for the suggestions, I figured it out and its answered below :)

Answer (score 0):

Right apologies! I've figured it out, the link_to is placed inside of this slightly hidden loop in my code:

```
   <% @tracks.each do |track| %>

       // lots more code in here

    <%= link_to track.user.username, user_path(@user) %>
<% end %>
```

so what i had to do was reference track first and then find the user like so:

```
track_path(track.user)
```

so my code now looks like so:

```
<% @tracks.each do |track| %>
   <%= link_to track.user.username, user_path(track.user) %>
<% end %>
```

and this works perfectly fine!

Thanks all :)

Ant